# smlnj interactive system: fatal error

Tags: sml, smlnj, google-chrome-os, crouton-os

Getting a strange error on my Crouton chroot on my Chromebook after `apt-get install smlnj` and attempting to call `sml` from the terminal, an error that I haven't been able to find anywhere else:

```
$ sml
/usr/lib/smlnj/bin/sml: Error -- unable to map 1179648 bytes, errno = 1
/usr/lib/smlnj/bin/sml: Fatal error -- unable to allocate memory object for BIBOP
```

Any guidance?

Comment: What a system is it and what does `free -m` show?

Comment: @barti_ddu I'm running Xubuntu in a chroot on a chromebook with just 2GB of memory. At any given time there's around 100 - 500 MB free. Is this prohibitive to sml?

Comment: AFAIR, 32MB should be enough for small scripts; however it seems that os is refusing sml's process to allocate even this amount of memory. Have you tried to increase/turn on swap temporarily?

Comment: Yeah, ~2GB swap is currently enabled on my system. Any ideas why the os could be refusing this?

Comment: Hmm, can you try to run sml/nj as follows: `sml @SMLalloc=128k` (or even smaller alloc size, say, 64/32/16/8k)? `run-sml` script may just do incorrect guess for your (celeron?) CPU.

Comment: I'm only able to set @SMLalloc to 128k before it says the option is too small. Unfortunately, I still get the same error, just with `unable to map n bytes` reduced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** This issue (bug #120) was fixed in SML/NJ version 110.77 ([release notes](http://www.smlnj.org/dist/working/110.77/110.77-README.html)) by enabling MAP_ANONYMOUS, which was previously unsupported in Linux. Installing the latest version of SMLNJ would be preferable to the solution below, since it doesn't require weakening the security of the system. If you do continue via modifying the permissions of `/dev`, it's advisable to remove `exec` permission after each session.

---

This problem is primarily reproducible in a **Chromium OS environment running ChrUbuntu or Crouton**, but may happen to other users in other environments who have a similar problem.

Running `strace` on `sml` gives this (attempted) operation before the error output:

```
open("/dev/zero", O_RDONLY)             = 4
mmap2(NULL, 1245184, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE, 4, 0) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

According to the [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html#ERRORS) documentation, `EPERM` indicates that the system is attempting to allocate memory with execute permission in a directory that is marked `noexec`.

Indeed, `mount` gives:

```
...
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=960456k,nr_inodes=240114,mode=755)
...
```

The solution is thus to remount `/dev` with `exec` permission:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,exec /dev
$ sml
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.75 [built: Thu May  9 05:41:01 2013]
-
```